# Making a project in php and i have to use Steam login api

Tags: php, steam-web-api

I want to practice on Steam login API and i don't have domain so can i use my local host XAMP/WAMP if yes then how to get an API key for it ?

Help will be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Give it a try yourself and in case encounter any error, then post your code and issue here. We'll be more than happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

When Steam asks for a domain to obtain an API key, they don't actually verify that requests come from that domain. It's just for their records, likely so they can trace API abuse back to keys.

As long as it looks like a domain to Steam, it ought to work. Just don't use anything legitimate or try to impersonate anyone, as I can't guarantee there won't be repercussions.

You've probably found the page, but if you haven't, you can get an API key [here](https://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey).